# Calling Python through ssh in Python script causes "Illegal instruction (core dumped)"

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, nvidia-jetson

I have a Python script `call.py` to log in to another machine through ssh and execute another Python script saved on this machine, something like this

```
# call.py
import os

# log into user@host machine and execute python script
os.system("sshpass -p password ssh user@host '( python3 my_script.py )'")
```

but when I try to run it I get this error

```
Illegal instruction     (core dumped)  ( python3 my_script.py )
```

I tried a few things:

- If I log into ssh and launch `python3 my_script.py` through the terminal it works
- I also tried running the same `call.py` script without the ssh part, so trying to launch `my_script.py` on the same machine and it works

It seems that only the combination of ssh + python inside python that gives me this error. Any pointers on what could cause the error will be very much appreciated.

**Edit:** I didn't realize it would play a role, but I'm adding now the important detail that the target machine is an Nvidia Jetson board.

Comment: "Illegal instruction" could mean that it's running an executable that was compiled for a different system. There could be differences in the `PATH` variable, causing a different executable to be run from the terminal vs. when run through ssh. Try using an absolute path like `/usr/bin/python3` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it pointed me in the right direction! There is a variable that I had to define in the target machines to make OpenCV work. Now to make `my_script.py` work I had to define it before calling `python3` in the same command.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution for my case, in case it can help someone else. As pointed out by [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14637/thomas), the problem was that I was working with different systems, in the specific my target machine was a Jetson while I was running ssh from my laptop.

On my Jetson board I had seen the `Illegal instruction (core dumped)` when trying to import OpenCV, to which the solution was to `export OPENBLAS_CORETYPE=ARMV8` to the `~/.bashrc`.

In order to make this work through ssh, I had to modify my command to call python this way:

`OPENBLAS_CORETYPE=ARMV8 python3`

and now it works!